# mySQL change multiple queries into single query

Tags: mysql

I have two mySQL tables:

tblcoach:  contains fields (coachid,coachschoolid, otherstuff)

tblschool: contains fields (schoolid,schooldivision)

I am trying to get a list of schools that is limited to the only those schools that are in the same schooldivision as a coach.

This code I have works, but is there someway to produce a single mySQL query to achieve the same results?

```
SELECT @cs := coachschoolid FROM tblcoach c;
SELECT @sd := s.schooldivision FROM tblschool s WHERE s.schoolid = @cs;
SELECT s2.schoolid, s2.schoolname FROM tblschool s2 WHERE schooldivision = @sd
```

Comment: Why dont you use a nested query? Replace your variables by the query itself and it becomes one query.

Answer (score 0):

Nest the queries:

```
select schoolId, schoolname
from tblschool
where 
    schooldivision = (
        select schooldivision from tblschool where schoolid = (
            select coachschoolid from tblcoach
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like it would work only with 1 coach.
You can use a self-join to do this:

```
SELECT s2.schoolid, s2.schoolname 
FROM tblschool s
INNER JOIN tblschool s2 on s.schooldivision = s2.schooldivision
WHERE s.schoolid = ?
```

Allows you to pass in the schoolID. If you want to pass in the coachID:

```
SELECT s2.schoolid, s2.schoolname 
FROM tblschool s
INNER JOIN tblschool s2 on s.schooldivision = s2.schooldivision
INNER JOIN tblcoach c on c.coachschoolid = s.schoolid
WHERE c.coachid = ?
```